# Deleting traces after dissolving several polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, dissolve

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.

I have a shapefile that has many catchments in it. I wanted to dissolve all these catchments to get just the boundary of the study area.

I used dissolve to do so

[image]

The problem is that I have found traces after I dissolved all polygons as below

[image]

How do I get rid of these traces?

**DATA**

You can download the shapefile from [**this link**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xbvvfh6cdha05ym/AAA53LEoyB3Un7_xBlmouJUra?dl=0).

Comment: Can you zoom in a lot further on one of these traces, please? And on the original data at the same extent.

Comment: @PolyGeo
Please, check update

Comment: I still cannot see whether these "traces" are lines or polygons or what linework they came from.  I need to be able to compare input vs output before I can start to think about what may have caused them.

Comment: Feature to line, feature to polygon using 1 selected

Comment: Try creating [topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/topologies/creating-a-topology.htm). Use `Must Not Have Gaps` for the [rule](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm). This is probably the safest way to identify problems which our eyes cannot detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to topological errors in the smaller catchment polygons, those lines appeared after dissolving. You can delete the lines appeared inside the dissolved polygon manually using [Delete Vertex](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/deleting-a-vertex.htm) from the editor tools.  Deleting vertex tool can delete a vertex or multiple vertices at a time to reshape the feature. To do that:

1. Click the Edit tool on the Editor toolbar and double-click
   the feature you want to edit
2. Click the Delete Vertex tool on the Edit Vertices toolbar and click
   the vertex you want to delete.
3. If you want to delete multiple vertices, click the Delete Vertex tool on the Edit Vertices toolbar and drag a box around the vertices.
4. Save edits.

The link above shows also the icons in the Edit Vertices toolbar that you can use to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

Try tool [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm):

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

Set the `cluster_tolerance` variable as small as possible.

Be sure to backup your data prior to running the tool since it will modify you data.